# Alerting the cgitb error?

Tags: python

Is there any possibility to check if cgitb has reported an error or to print into a variable / file the error? I want to check that because even though the request to python file was successful, the cgitb has reported an error and the script won't work as intended so i want to alert that on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Your script should `try` / `except` catch the error, and handle it as desired, such as including the error on your page, and/or calling cgitb.handler((ex_type, ex_val, tb)). Or interpose your own handler.

See also the `logdir` parameter that enable() accepts:  https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/cgitb.html